# Recursively indexing lists within for-loop

Tags: r

I am producing a simple nest loop which should create a 30x30  indexed lists however, my loop only returns 30 list elements:

for example:

```
x1 <- rnorm(30,1, 1)
z1 <- rnorm(30,0 ,2)
probit <- c()
binom <- list()
for(i in seq_along(x1)){
  probit[i] <- pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i])
  for(j in seq_along(z1)){
    print(rbinom(30, j, pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i])))
    binom[i][[j]] <- rbinom(30, j, pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i]))
  }
}
```

when printing out `length(binom)`, it prints 30 but I expected 900. The print statement seems to print all 900 except that not all are assigned to the list.

Comment: It is ok, 30 is the length of the list, but each of the 30 element of the list has 30 elements. Try `sum(sum(sapply(binom, length))`. There are however better ways to do this.

Comment: @RicVillalba no thats not right, It should produce a sample of 30 elements for each index of `j` and store these as individual lists for each index `i`. Therefore, for index `1` of `i` then I should have a list of 30 elements each so 30x30. Then so forth, so essentially, 30x30x30. But instead I get 30x30

Comment: How did this code run? its incorrect subscription!, Should be `binom <- vector('list', 30)` then do `binom[[i]][[j]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
x1 <- rnorm(30,1, 1)
z1 <- rnorm(30,0 ,2)
probit <- c()
binom <- vector('list', 30)
for(i in seq_along(x1)){
  probit[i] <- pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i])
  for(j in seq_along(z1)){
    #print(rbinom(30, j, pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i])))
    binom[[i]][[j]] <- list(rbinom(30, j, pnorm(-1 + x1[i] + 0.4*z1[i])))
  }
}
```

This gives you 30 * 30 * 30